# How to use AutoMapper and DTO's with two connected tables in ASP.NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model, automapper, dto

I have this code below(2 connected models one to one)

```
public partial class Dish
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DishName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public DishDescription DishDescription { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<OrderDish> Orders { get; set; }
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<DishCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
    public partial class DishDescription
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Calories { get; set; }
        public int Protein { get; set; }
        public int Fats { get; set; }
        public int Carbohydrates { get; set; }
        public int DishId { get; set; }

        public Dish Dish { get; set; }
    }
```

DTO:

```
public class GetAllDishesDto
    {
        public string DishName { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public DishDescription DishDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class DishDescriptionDto
    {
        public int Calories { get; set; }
        public int Protein { get; set; }
        public int Fats { get; set; }
        public int Carbohydrates { get; set; }
    }
```

AutoMapper:

```
    public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Dish, GetAllDishesDto>();
            CreateMap<DishDescription, DishDescriptionDto>();
        }
    }
```

Service:

```
public async Task<ICollection<GetAllDishesDto>> GetAllDishes()
        { 
            return await _dishDeliveryContext.Dishes
                .Include(d => d.DishDescription)
                .Select(d => _mapper.Map<GetAllDishesDto>(d))
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

at the result i have responce below

[image]

BUT I NEED THIS ONE

[image]

help please

i tried to do this

```
 public async Task<ICollection<GetAllDishesDto>> GetAllDishes()
        { 
            return await _dishDeliveryContext.Dishes
                .Include(d => _mapper.Map<DishDescriptionDto>(d))
                .Select(d => _mapper.Map<GetAllDishesDto>(d))
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

but it was a bad idea...
i want to learn more about automapper and dto's, but now i cant understand how it works, maybe i should not using method Map() with second DTO, i think i houl use another one instead of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is that you mismatched the nested model name for your Dto. It should contain `DishDescriptionDto` rather than `DishDescription` in your another Dto model.

```
public class GetAllDishesDto
{
    public string DishName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public DishDescriptionDto DishDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Another point is that it's nice to use `.ProjectTo()` before `ToListAsync()` so Automapper helps EntityFramework to reduce the sql query and exclude unused fields. The query should look like this

```
public async Task<ICollection<GetAllDishesDto>> GetAllDishes()
{ 
    return await _dishDeliveryContext.Dishes
        .ProjectTo<GetAllDishesDto>(configuration)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```